# Android running onChildAdded method every time view is accessed through startActivity

Tags: android

I was wondering why my android application is running fireBase onChildAdded every time I access the view through start activity. I only want to read from the fireBase database once, and from then on I use onResume to populate the list with the last entry in the databas (if any were added).

However it is running the onChildAdded every time I use startActitivity to access the view. So this means it doesn't happen when I press the back button to this view.

It's slowing down my application a lot having to repopulate the list from the database every time the user goes back to this page from the home-screen.

Here's a video showcasing how much faster it is when I press back to access the screen when compared to accessing it from the home-screen and pressing on "nightclub" card: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VJxsHT14PU8&feature=youtu.be

My onCreate Method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // start tracing to "/sdcard/calc.trace"
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_nightclub_search);

    // Map and camera Positions
    // Retrieve location and camera position from saved instance state.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mLastKnownLocation = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_LOCATION);
        mCameraPosition = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(KEY_CAMERA_POSITION);
    }

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    // Build the Play services client for use by the Fused Location Provider and the Places API.
    // Use the addApi() method to request the Google Places API and the Fused Location Provider.
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */,
                    this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    // List View
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.venueList);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    venueList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(nightclub_search.this, R.layout.list_layout, venueList);

    // Fill the list view from the fireBase
    fillListView();

    // Button
    Button addClub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addClub);
    addClub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(nightclub_search.this, venue_add.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

This is how I am calling the view from the home-screen:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);

    CardView cardBar = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardBar);
    CardView cardNightclub = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cardNightClub);

    cardBar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(home_screen.this, bar_search.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    cardNightclub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(home_screen.this, nightclub_search.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}}
```

And finally this is how I populate the list from firebase which is called within onCreate (and nowhere else):

```
// Fills the list for the initial load of the application
protected void fillListView(){

    // Loading bar
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(nightclub_search.this);
    dialog.setMessage("Loading Venues...");
    dialog.show();


    // Separate this from the main thread so that it runs faster
    Runnable run = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    // Loading dialog for getting fireBase entries
                    count++;
                    Log.d("Firebase", "onChildAddedFROMFILLLISTVIEW:" + dataSnapshot.getKey());
                    // A new venue has been added, add it to the displayed list
                    Nightclub nightclub = dataSnapshot.getValue(Nightclub.class);
                    clubList.add(nightclub);
                    venueList.add(nightclub.name);
                    // Read in location and add marker on map
                    addMarkers(nightclub, days);
                    // Add to listView
                    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                    // Remove the loading bar when we've reached this point
                    if (count >= (dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount() - 1)){
                        count = 0;
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    };

    Thread fillListThread = new Thread(run);
    fillListThread.start();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting launch mode 'singleTask' in manifest for activity so that onCreate will be called only once while initializing activity and there after all calls will be given to 'onNewIntent' method until new instance is not created in activity back stack.

Comment: Unfortunately it still completely rebuilds the list when entering the view from the home-screen.

I'm thinking it has something to do with the database reference listener. Other things in onCreate aren't activating (like the loading dialog box), so it must be just calling the onChildAdded from my reference listener every time it is entered from start activity. I will update the question to reflect these new findings.

Answer (score 0):

The `startActivity(Intent intent)` method creates a new activity instance unless you set some flags to it. To recover an existing activity instance through intent try using this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(nightclub_search.this, venue_add.class);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(i);
```

or add this to your Activity tag on manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.company.ActivityName"
    android:launchMode="singleTask">
</activity>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, unfortunately neither of these work. I'm thinking it's not running onCreate but instead the firebase "onChildAdded" is being called every time the view is accessed through start activity (but not when pressing back to the activity).